# Unable to Clearinterval after set?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, setinterval, clearinterval

I created a slideshow(`function slide()`):
I want this function to start when click on 'play' 
and pause when click on 'pause'.
I used setinterval it works, only clearinterval refuse to work, what am I doing wrong?

```html
<div id='play' onclick='play()'><img src='image1/fleche.png'></div>
<div id='pause' onclick='stop()'><img src='image1/break.png'></div>
```

```js
function play(){
    var test = setInterval(slide,500);}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(test);}
```

Comment: `test` should not be defined in `stop`, i'd expect an error in strict mode.

Comment: LIke this? function stop(){
 clearInterval();}

Comment: My second problem is that if you click several time on play, the slideshow start to bug. Any idea?

Comment: use interval IDs to manage the events [WindowTimers MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because "test" is undefined inside the stop function.
For your code to work, you can make the "test" variable global, like this:-

```
var test = null;

function play(){
    test = setInterval(slide,500);}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(test);}
```

Comment: though it does pollute the global scope...

Comment: @proefkip, if you have another question, post another question, please don't ask multiple questions and esspecially don't ask questions in comments

Comment: okay that is a good tip

Comment: @proefkip you can do something like this (although code could be improved a lot):--
`
var test = null,
 isTimerOn = false;

function play(){
 if(!isTimerOn)
 {
  test = setInterval(slide,500); 
 }
 isTimerOn = true;
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(test);
 isTimerOn = false;
}

function slide(){
 isTimerOn = false;
 // Below is the code to actually slide.
} `

Comment: i have got the same problem. when click on play my slideshow becomes messy

Comment: @proefkip can you share a JS fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a9bfedu7/

Answer (score 3):

this is a classic use case for the [Revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript):

```
var mySlideShow = (function () {
    var intervalHolder;

    //this is private to the closure
    var slide = function(){
          //whatever slide does?
    }

    function play(){
      intervalHolder = setInterval(slide,500);
    }

    function stop(){
           clearInterval(intervalHolder);
     }

    return{
      play:play,
      stop:stop
    };
})();
```

call it thus:

```
<div id='play' onclick='mySlideShow.play()'><img src='image1/fleche.png'></div>
<div id='pause' onclick='mySlideShow.stop()'><img src='image1/break.png'></div>
```

The advantages of this method are:

- Does not pollute the global scope with variables
- > This pattern allows the syntax of our scripts to be more consistent.
  >   It also makes it more clear at the end of the module which of our
  >   functions and variables may be accessed publicly which eases
  >   readability.

Comment: No idea why OP didn't accept your answer.

Comment: Not really the quick fix. But it is the better way. If the others addresses his problem then good for him :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `test` is a variable declared inside `play()`, and it exists only inside that function. You have to declare it outside:

```js
var test;
function play(){
    test = setInterval(function(){
 console.log("hello")
 },500);
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(test);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play()">play</button>
<button onclick="stop()">stop</button>
```

Comment: Of course the best way to say thank you is to upvote... @proefkip. It's probably a good idea to have a read though the [help]

Comment: it is the first day i am using this site, i clicked on the marked and put the answer which best helped me on the top